# IabHelper launchPurchaseFlow google play In-app Billing does not find product

Tags: java, android

- I downloaded the sample app
- Got my key from the developer console
- Put the proper permissions in my manifest

Nothing helps: I got always product not found...
Thanx - Ralf

here is the code, Java, Android Studio
    // Does the user have the professional upgrade? should be an In-App product

```
private static Boolean _PROFESSIONAL = false;

// Debug tag, for logging
private static final String TAG_BILLING = "BillingService";

// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001; // 10002 does not help either...

// The helper object
IabHelper mHelper = null;

static final String SKU_PROFESSIONAL = "com...";

private String base64EncodedPublicKey = "KSRWbpF........... from Google play Developer Console

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh no, there was a problem.
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, null, mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PROFESSIONAL);
        _PROFESSIONAL = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
    }
};

// User clicked the menu upgrade professional
private void Upgrade() {
    String payload = sMyPurchaseToken;

    // tested, but no help
    // define IabHelper.flagEndAsync() as public, and add iabHelper.flagEndAsync() before iabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(...)
    // mHelper.flagEndAsync();

    // could be tested: this, "android.test.purchased", 10002

    /////////// here the program shows the Google Play message that the programm does not exist... or is not configured for payment...
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MyActivity.this, SKU_PROFESSIONAL, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

    //mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "android.test.purchased", 10002, is ok
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (mHelper == null) return;

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    }
    else {
    }
}

boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
    return true;
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PROFESSIONAL)) {
            _PROFESSIONAL = true;
        }
    }
};

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
        }
        else {
            complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, you need to provide some code for us to help solve the problem with. Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read on how to [write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to compile an installer, upload to google play in alpha, add products as specified in the code,  publish app in alpha. Wait for few hours to see google play updated. Install application from google play alpha publish and check, you will see products. But this app will not work in debug mode.